# formatting gridview cell text on rowdatabound

Tags: asp.net, gridview

The following code is my rowdatabound event for my gridview. It works for everything other than the cell text formatting as a currency. In fact the code line where i format the currency
causes the code to err. If i comment out the FormatCurrency line the code works fine. Why does that line a). not format the cell's text and b). cause the error?

```
    Protected Sub gvDataRetrieval_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvDataRetrieval.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim dateindex As Integer = GetColumnIndexByHeaderText(gvDataRetrieval, "date")
        e.Row.Cells(dateindex).Text = Split(e.Row.Cells(dateindex).Text, " ")(0)
        For i As Integer = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
            e.Row.Cells(i).Font.Size = 10
            e.Row.Cells(i).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
            If i > dateindex Then
                If Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells(i).Text) < 0 Then
                    e.Row.Cells(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                Else
                    e.Row.Cells(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                End If
            End If
            e.Row.Cells(i).Text = FormatCurrency(e.Row.Cells(i).Text, 0)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format, which doesnt seem to be the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone else said above, your code will error out if you attempt to format a non-numeric value as a currency and it seems to me that you are not doing that.

Instead, if you want a particular column to be formatted as a currency, use the DataFormatString property of the column as so:

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="YourCurrencyField" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
```

Obviously, you still need to make sure that your field is a valid number that can be formatted as a currency.

Comment: The grid is dynamic. How can I set that property in the code behind? will this work? I have already tried converting the cell text to decimal and double and the formatting and fore color change don't like each other together

Comment: By dynamic you mean that you create the columns in code behind or simply that the columns are autogenerated? Either way, you can set the DataFormatString property programmatically as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
e.Row.Cells(i).Text = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells(i).Text).ToString("c0")
```

Instead of

```
e.Row.Cells(i).Text = Format(e.Row.Cells(i).Text, "c0").ToString()
```

Comment: No good, the problem seems to lie in the fact that the compiler doesnt like the forecolor change AND the string format together... At least not how I have been trying to do it

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
 e.Row.Cells(i).Text = Format(e.Row.Cells(i).Text, "c0").ToString()
```

into the If function. That line was not checking if it was date column. Probably trying to convert a date to currency

```
        If i > dateindex Then
            If Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells(i).Text) < 0 Then
                e.Row.Cells(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            Else
                e.Row.Cells(i).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
            End If
            e.Row.Cells(i).Text = Format(e.Row.Cells(i).Text, "c0").ToString()
        End If
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried it there. I get the same error although now the error display on the browser highlights the "If Convert.ToDecimal.... code line. If i comment out the If i > dateindex sequence the cell text will format as currency but it wont do the forecolor change AND the currency format...Why?  Also, this line definetly works as the currency formatter.....e.Row.Cells(1).Text = FormatCurrency(e.Row.Cells(1).Text, 0)

Comment: is it possible that once I  format the cell's text as a currency the Convert.ToDecimal is no longer valid?

Comment: step through your code and see inspect the variables value e.g. dateindex, e.Row.Cells(i).Text - there could be some invalid numeric values after dateindex grid columns

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in C# and solved by converting the text to a double first, then formatting the double as a string.

I know this is VB and not C# but I thought I'd share my solution as it came up in my Google results, and might help someone out.

```
double d;
Double.TryParse(r.Cells[i].Text, out d);
e.Cells[i].Text = String.Format("{0:C0}", d).ToString();
```